# How to evaluate value of expression value in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is it possible to evaluate value of expression value?  For example,

```
context: {
 "foo" : "bar" ,
 "bar" : "abc" ,
 "abc" : "xyz" 
}
```

Now to print value of foo we will use `{{foo}}` . Can we get the value of value of bar?  Like this.

```
{{ {{foo}} }}
```

This doesn't work though. Similar thing we can do in javascript,

`context[context.foo] ]` to get the value.  Or any long/nested expression: `context[context[context[foo] ] ]`.

Is it possible to do something like this in handlebars?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would use the [lookup](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) helper:

```
{{lookup this foo}}
```